# magento Change logout url link for some phtml pages

Tags: php, magento

There is "Logout" link all over the site. If we click on Logout, it will redirect to this page.

http://sitename/customer/account/logoutSuccess/

but in some phtml pages for example , in below page

http://sitename.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

if we click on "Logout", it should logout but redirect to following url :

http://sitename.com/marketplace.

In google i found redirecting for entire site. but i need only for some pages.

I am using following code : Accountcontroller.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php'; 
class Webkul_Marketplace_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{ 

public function marketlogoutAction() 
{ 
$this->_getSession()->logout() 
->renewSession(); 
//add your code here 
$this->_redirect('marketplace'); 

echo "something";
exit();
} 

public function logoutAction() 
{ 
$this->_getSession()->logout() 
->renewSession(); 

$this->_redirect('*/*/logoutSuccess'); 
}
```

**Data.php** [app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Helper ]

```
 public function getLogoutUrl() 
{ 
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); 
if (strpos($currentUrl,'marketplaceaccount') !== false) { 
return $this->_getUrl('marketplace'); 
}else 
{ 
return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/logout'); 
} 
}
```

but when i log out from some phtml pages, its redirecting to the page that i required, but its not logged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code..
data.php

```
 public function getLogoutUrl() 
{ 
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); 
if (strpos($currentUrl,'marketplaceaccount') !== false) { 
return $this->_getUrl('marketplace/account/marketlogout'); 
} else if (strpos($currentUrl,'mpshippingmanager') !== false) { 
return $this->_getUrl('marketplace/account/mpshippingmanagerlogout'); 
} else if (strpos($currentUrl,'mpmassuploadaddons') !== false) { 
return $this->_getUrl('marketplace/account/mpmassuploadaddonslogout'); 
}else if (strpos($currentUrl,'mpassignproduct') !== false) { 
return $this->_getUrl('marketplace/account/mpassignproductlogout'); 
}else 
{ 
return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/logout'); 
} 
}
```

this is for action. add one function in Accountcontroller

```
public function mpmassuploadaddonslogoutAction() 
{ 

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout(); 
//add your code here 
$this->_redirect('mpmassuploadaddons'); 

}
public function mpmassuploadaddonslogoutAction() 
{ 

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout(); 
//add your code here 
$this->_redirect('mpmassuploadaddons'); 

}
public function mpassignproductlogoutAction() 
{ 

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout(); 
//add your code here 
$this->_redirect('mpassignproduct'); 

}  public function marketlogoutAction() 
{ 

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout(); 
//add your code here 
$this->_redirect('marketplace'); 

}
```

Comment: i added this in Accountcontroller.php , but its not working.

Comment: if i remove helper [Data.php] file than it will log out, but it will not redrect to "marketplace".

Comment: Did the logout successful

Comment: no, now if i click on log out from anywhere on the site, than its echo "something" . but if i log out from marketplace pages, it not log out, but redirecting to marketplace page as like before

Comment: this is working now : "return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/marketlogout');" but what i need to do for other extensions?

Comment: tell me url of that extension?

Comment: http://2.kidsdial.com/mpassignproduct/index/index/

http://2.kidsdial.com/mpassignproduct/index/mpassignproductlist/

http://2.kidsdial.com/mpmassuploadaddons/index/importnew/

http://2.kidsdial.com/mpshippingmanager/shipping/

if you have login details , please login and check

Comment: these have own login too?

Comment: if you tell general procedure https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Mass-upload.html

https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Seller-Price-Comparison.html

Comment: please login with email : kidsdial2@gmail.com pw : kidsdial2

Comment: than please visit this link : http://2.kidsdial.com/mpassignproduct/index/index/ and http://2.kidsdial.com/mpmassuploadaddons/index/importnew/

Comment: its working. i am trying for another extension , i will let you know about the result....

Comment: i have 2 more extensions with following url

1)mpmassuploadaddons
2)mpshippingmanager

please give me updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your helper (Data.php) function to:

`return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/marketlogout');`

instead of
`$this->_getUrl('marketplace')`

Otherwise it's just redirect you to the marketplace url

Comment: i used this : return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/marketplace');  but still not logging out

Comment: it should redirect to marketplace url . this is i required , along with it should log out also.

but that is not happening

Comment: I edited my answer, should be customer/account/marketlogout

Comment: i used this : return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/marketlogout'); but still same result.

Comment: hmm it should work, I noticed on the other answer you are adding echo and exit, make sure you are not exiting before you call $this->_getSession()->logout() 
->renewSession();

Comment: check the updated question, i echoed after $this->_getSession()->logout() ->renewSession();  .

Comment: now if i click on log out from anywhere on the site, than its echo "something" . but if i log out from marketplace pages, it not log out, but redirecting to marketplace page as like before.

Comment: before i asked the question here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92017/change-logout-url-link-for-some-phtml-pages/92028?noredirect=1#comment123148_92028 you can check with this, you will get more details about question.

Comment: this is working now : "return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/marketlogout');" but what i need to do for other extensions?

Comment: glad that it's working now, I'm not sure about the "other extensions" part, can you clarify

Comment: in entire site, if we click on "log out " button , than it should logout.

but for some pages, means if customer is on some extensions pages, in those pages, if we click on

"LOg out" button, than it should redirect to "marketplace" [ http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/ ]

now i got an answer for 2 extensions as in  other answer gave by "Qaisar Satti". see one more comment.

Comment: but we have 2 more extensions, http://2.kidsdial.com/mpshippingmanager/shipping/

http://2.kidsdial.com/mpmassuploadaddons/index/importnew/ .these are other 2 extensions link.


url are 1)mpmassuploadaddons 2)mpshippingmanager.

what i need to do to work this for these 2 extensions also?